# How do I repeat div structure for each object in json array?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that produces a json array. I know that if I wanted to display the following Json on my page:

```
[{"FruitId":1, "Name":"Apple", "Description":"Red Delicious"}]
```

I could do something like this for the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="fruitName"></div>
    <div id="fruitId"></div>
    <span id="fruitDescription" class="test"></span>
</div>
```

Then this in the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fruitId = $("#fruitId");
    var fruitName = $("#fruitName");
    var fruitDescription = $("#fruitDescription");

    $.get("https://example.com/some/json", function (data) {    
        $.each(data, function (index, row) {
        $(fruitId).html(row.fruitId)
        $(fruitName).html(row.Name)
        $(fruitDescription).html(row.Description)
   });
});
```

Lets say I had more than one `fruit`. How do I loop the HTML structure in the javascript so that that `div:row` structure displays or repeats for each fruit in the json array?

Answer (score 1):

You can write wrapper class to all fruits as

```
<div id="fruits-container">
</div>
```

Now, next task would be to write a function which creates fruit div which contains FruitId, Name and Description.

Algorithm would be like,

```
function appendFruit(id, name, description ) {
    // create fruit div
    // add class to div
    // create children for Name, Id, Description
    // append element to fruitsContainer
}
```

Now, we can loop over data and call this function for specific data received.